# django - static image not showing up in template

Tags: django, django-models

I'm just trying to display a basic image that is stored in my static folder but nothing is showing up. I have ran `collectstatic` but nothing.

**Path:**
/static/logos/IMG_1793.jpg

(That is what is shown when printing `tenant.image.url`)

**Settings.html:**

```
<img src="{{ imagePath }}" alt="{{ tenant.name }}">
```

I have also tried: `src="{% static imagePath %}"`

**Views.py**

```
def settingsPage(request):
    tenant = get_tenant(request)
    imagePath = tenant.image.url
    context = {'tenant': tenant, 'imagePath': imagePath}
    return render(request, 'setting/settings.html', context)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subdomain = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/logos/', blank=True)


class TenantAwareModel(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: if may ask did you configure the static root media settings  in your main urls.py  file, if yes then i guess you may want to  append url in path like this: ~~~ <img src="{{ imagePath.url }}" alt="{{ tenant.name }}">

Comment: Can you please  add your model.py to your question to help in solving your problem.

Comment: @AbuGodda I have updated to include the models.py file

Comment: I hope my solution solve your challenge @user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solving your challenge its very straight forward, first it is relatively import to set media url and static path in your setting.py file:

```
# Goes in the setting.py 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
```

Then you link your media and static path in your main urls.py to load static files and at the sometime save your files in the static and media directory.

```
#Your main urls.py 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then we focus  on our view.py where all of the manipulation of rendering data in the frontend take place. what you have done is basically good and so i will stick to your convention! but you missed in you getting your data from the backend, in which
won't possibly work for you to render images, i suppose that's where our challenge comes from.

```
# our view.py 
# first make sure to import the tenant models

from .models import Tenant

def settingsPage(request):
    # Here we are getting all tenant objects from our backend database
    # to render in the frontend template 
    tenants = Tenant.objects.all()
    context = {'tenants': tenants}
    return render(request, 'setting/settings.html', context)
```

After we have a view for our data we focus on rendering the data in our frontend template. which is where we are going to show our images. since our view is not a detail view we would need to loop through the data from the view in our template to get the images rendered.

```
# our template where the image will be shown.
# here we are looping to get all the objects in tenant
{% for tenant in tenants %} 
<div>
<img src="{{ tenant.image.url }}" alt="">
    {{ tenant.name }}
    {{ tenant.subdomain}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an `img` tag `src` attribute you normally put the URL of an image. So if you know the URL just put it there instead of putting the image name.

```
<img src="{{ tenant.image.url }}" alt="{{ tenant.name }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in developer mode

in settings.py

make sure debug is false (`DEBUG = False`) 
and you specified `STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'`